# IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 11

Tags: python

Please can one advise why i am getting this error message please:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 # import some data to play with
      2 nd = train_x_all.values
----> 3 X = nd[:,[11,5]]  # we only take the first two features.
      4 Y = train_y_all.values
      5

IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 11

```
# import some data to play with
nd = train_x_all.values
X = nd[:,[11,5]]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = train_y_all.values

logreg = LogisticRegressionCV(cv=10)

# Create an instance of Logistic Regression Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)
x_min, x_max = X[:,0].min() - 1, X[:,0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:,1].min() - 1, X[:,1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max,0.1),
                     np.arange(y_min,y_max, 0.1))
Z = logreg.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.plot()
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.4, cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y,  cmap = plt.cm.brg)
plt.title("Logistic Regression")
plt.xlabel("FamilyN")
plt.ylabel("Fare")
plt.legend(Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wouldn't "index 11" be the 12th element?  For any collection of size 11, that's out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is 0-based, so if list's size is 11, its largest index is 10